# Determining relationship type from BreezeJs entity

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, ef-code-first, breeze, data-modeling

Given any BreezeJs entity, how can you determine it's relation to it's navigation properties--i.e. does it have a 1-to-1, 1-to-0-or-1, 1-to-n, etc relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Use [getProperty](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html%23method_getProperty) to retrieve the property's [info](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/NavigationProperty.html%23property_isScalar).  The `isScalar` property will be true when it's a 1-1 relationship and false when it's a 1-N relationship.